# Why doesn't my Nokia Lumia 610 synchronize my new Microsoft account?

Tags: microsoft-account, 7.5, nokia-lumia-610

I reset my Nokia Lumia 610 with Windows Phone 7.5. On restarting it will not synchronize the Microsoft account I created (with a brand new email never used before) just for this phone. Whilst the account works fine, it cannot "see" any other WP devices.

Comment: What other WP devices do you mean? Is there an error message? Also, saying that the account does not sync seems a bit contradictory with "the account works fine".

Comment: Sorry, I mean the account on the phone will not sync whilst the same Microsoft Account on the PC works fine (it doesnt give any error messages) but doesn't see the Nokia Wphone with the same MS account.